# How to access the TTTableItem of a TTTableViewController?

Tags: ios, ios4, three20

Good day to everyone out there... I've been stuck with this problem the whole afternoon. I know via the -didSelectObject:atIndexPath method one can access the TTTableItem via the detected gesture recognizer. The only problem is that I can't seem to access the TTableItem without having to use the said method.

The fact that i'm asking this is that I have a tableView for selection purposes, single selection to be specific. I am able to work on the selection part without any hurdles, but as soon as i start to scroll the tableView, the tableView display states which are incorrect with respect to each cell.

I hope you may have insights into this, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out...

All I had to do was set a reference to the TTTableItem as the program goes into the didSelectObject:atIndexPath method. So that as soon as the cells are reused, and the application goes into the setObject method of the UITableViewCell, the exact values are evaluated and the behavior corrected.